# Query não está atualizando valores nulos

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Estou analisando os dados de um banco de alunos, os dados são inseridos pelos próprios usuários, e eu não posso alterar o formato das tabelas e do banco em si, apenas modificar os valores dos registros para padronizar alguns campos.

No campo de nacionalidade, existem alguns registros brasileiros errados, escritos como brazeleiro ou brasilero, etc. Os registros de outras nacionalidades eu não queria modificar, então fiz a seguinte query, essa lista na query são todos os outros registros fora os brasileiros:

```
UPDATE base
   SET nacionalidade = 'Brasileira'
   WHERE nacionalidade not in ('Americana', 'asdf', 'VENEZUELA', 'VENEZUELANO - BRASILEIRO');
```

No campo ainda tinha alguns valores nulos. Esses campos eu também não queria mexer, mas acabei rodando o update, e acontece que ele não atualizou os campos nulos. Minha dúvida é justamente querer saber por que ele não atualizou?

Comment: Creio que você deveria utilizar a cláusula IS NULL para modificar o campo que seja NULL.

Answer (score 5):

A razão é que uso de operadores de comparação com NULL não se comporta como seria esperado.

Isso pode ser verificado da seguinte forma:

```
WHERE nacionalidade NOT IN ('Americana', 'asdf', 'VENEZUELA', 'VENEZUELANO - BRASILEIRO');
```

pode ser traduzido para:

```
WHERE NOT ( nacionalidade = 'Americana' OR nacionalidade = 'asdf' OR (...))
```

que, eliminado o NOT, é equivalente a:

```
WHERE nacionalidade != 'Americana' AND nacionalidade != 'asdf' AND (...))
```

Em `WHERE NOT ( nacionalidade = 'Americana' OR nacionalidade = 'asdf' OR (...))`, se a comparação com NULL retornasse FALSE(o esperado), a expressão seria verdadeira.
No entanto sabemos que nenhum campo foi alterado. É como se, neste caso, a comparação com NULL retornasse TRUE.

Em `WHERE nacionalidade != 'Americana' AND nacionalidade != 'asdf' AND (...))` o resultado esperado é que a comparação retorne TRUE e a expressão seria verdadeira.  No entanto sabemos que nenhum campo foi alterado. É como se, neste caso, a comparação com NULL retornasse FALSE.

Então, como é que, em duas expressões equivalentes, a comparação se comporta de forma distinta?

Na realidade o resultado de uma comparação com  NULL não é falso ou verdadeiro, nem maior ou menor,  é UNKNOWN ou NULL, consoante a implementação.

NULL indica ausência de um valor, valor desconhecido, nada.
Não se consegue comparar algo que existe com algo que não existe ou é desconhecido.
O resultado do uso de qualquer operador de comparação com NULL é sempre UNKNOWN e resultado é ignorado.

Daí a existência do operador IS NULL.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que este operador não considera os valores nulos. Para funcionar, o seu `UPDATE` deveria ser assim:

```
UPDATE base
   SET nacionalidade = 'Brasileira'
   WHERE (nacionalidade not in ('Americana', 'asdf', 'VENEZUELA', 'VENEZUELANO - BRASILEIRO') or nacionalidade IS NULL)
```

[Aqui tem um post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values) onde se comenta o mesmo problema.